# How to emphasize/mark one option over the other?

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, mobile-application, controls, psychology

I'm attaching screenshot of the current section.

[image]

The left option, is the free option(obviously), while the right one, is the paid option, marked with "locked" emoji.

I'm trying to increase the "awareness" of the right(paid) button, and even create a more positive connotation to him, comparing the the "free option".
Maybe, some how make them feel like the free option, is "cheaper"/"degraded quality", comparing to the paid one, which is far better?

**What would you suggest, from your experience?**

Edit :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix: Make the paid option look more attractive. In your current design, both options are equal in look except for the lock icon (which you may consider removing as it may deter users).

Here's a simple fix to the icons:

[image: Low Quality vs. Full HD]

Side note: I wouldn't argue that Full HD is perfect for social media, which is overwhelmingly compressed and low-res pictures and videos. Maybe rephrase to, "Looks great on any device". You also might consider including all the additional reasons to upgrade on the first view to interest users.

**Edit to Answer Comment 10/16**

Based on your other screenshot, I'm going to assume your view is a 9:16 vertical space. Under each option, maybe list out the details and benefits. For example:

*Select your Export Resolution*

Low Quality

- Free
- 1280 x 720p
- 3 exports

Full HD

- $2.99
- 1960 x 1080p
- One-time purchase for unlimited exports

This or something similar would negate for the need of the lock, as the user will see up-front what each option gets them and costs.

Example (From Soundcloud Pro page):

[image: Soundcloud Pro]

Comment: Hey Alan! Thank you for your response! :) about the small lock addon, how would you "explain" to the user that this option is unlocked, if he would be removed? I mean, i've attached the lock only to some how hint the user that this options is currently not available to him. What would you advise? Plus, i can't seem to think on a way, that it'll explain the user all the pros of this option(listed below the button) + explain to him that this options is locked. Would love to hear your response! :)

Comment: See post edit for answer

Comment: Hey Alan, again thank you for your response! The one thing which i'm banging my head over and over is the act of "separation". Meaning, that i do aware of the art of "minimal clicks possible". Tho, wouldn't it be too much info provided, that could be interpreted as a "pressure" from the app, to take action? I mean. I understand that avoid this extra screen is basically a good thing, tho, would it more "inviting" to separate it? I mean, the users might avoid this act only by seeing the $ tag below it, I might be wrong. Would love to hear your response. That's my last question. :)

Comment: Without proper A/B testing, it's always challenging determining which method of presentation is the best. I'm a firm believer in as little steps as possible, but you also bring up a good point of intimidating the user with a price. Either way, the user will have to "take action" to get full HD, so why not be up front with pricing? I've attached another screenshot to my answer.

Comment: Good example. The one answer i can think of regarding to your question. In my perspective, we are mixing two different stuff. Think about that that way. We have two separate actions we are trying to "pass" to the user. First one, that the Full HD(etc) option is the more exclusive/better one. Secondly, we want him to buy the one-time In App Purchase. The main reason why iv'e created two screens. Is that in the first one, i'm trying only to make them realize the second options(paid) is better. Without providing external info(as for, what would you choose, Mercedes or Peugeot).

Comment: Than after he clicks, i explain to him how can he open this option(and getting him "do" the second action we wanted, which is the iAP option). After explaining this two, do you still convince showing the data up-front, might be a better way? without A/B for the matter(i know it's needed, but i need to choose an option)

Comment: Yes, I am answering your question without full context/understanding of the design. If you believe an iAP page would be a better outlet for displaying the cost, then trust your judgement. You know the app better than I do. :)

Comment: Would you like to check it? :) Video to Photo - Extract Single Frames in Full HD by Roi Mulia https://appsto.re/il/Np-teb.i

Comment: Than we'll have the same context

Answer (score 3):

You can use a button with background for the CTA button and a ghost button  only for the button that you want to be less visible (or just text / background with a smaller opacity).

[image]

The second option is to use a bold color for the CTA button and a neutral color for the second option (both with background or both ghost buttons).

You also can try different grades of elevation (raised buttons stand out more than flat buttons) and I think you should keep the CTA button on right.

Look also at this example on [Material Design Blog](https://material.google.com/components/buttons.html#buttons-button-types):

[image]

Comment: Hey Madalina, Thank you for your response! What do you think about this design? (i've tried) http://prntscr.com/cv2ow5

Comment: @RoiMulia I think is ok. I'm not sure if is necessary the bold weight in the CTA button, but I think this is the best option, with background for the main option. Clean, enough contract, a good solution. The white border for the first button can be a good idea too. You can decide easier how contrast is necessary for your UI.

Comment: Thanks! :) i've tried another thing, which is unsymmetrical, tho,it gives more attention to the second button. What do you think? Am i wrong? http://prntscr.com/cv46hf

Comment: @RoiMulia You are right, the second button gives more attention in the last image. I think it could be a little too much contrast between the two options, but if this you search, it is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

A way companies compare the free vs paid options is to list all the features each includes. Normally the paid version includes all free features and extra ones.

In your case it looks like the difference between the two options is not about features but about quality of the product. You can make a comparison including products destination platform such as:

• Acceptable for preview purposes (both)

• Perfect for Social media embed (paid one)

More features and checks on the paid version will gain more visibility. As well as full understand of what are the pros of paid version from the user perspective, and it will be up to him to decide.

-

Note about the "locked" emoji: I am not entirely sure what are you trying to transmit the user with it. To me it transmits some safety feature, or even an option which is locked (not available).

Comment: Hey Alvaro! Thank you for your respond. The first step which i'm trying to achieve, is to clarify the user, that he has two options. When he's clicking the "paid" option, a  overlay windows pops up(i'll attach a screenshot), listing all the pros. So generally, i need to make him press the paid button, afterwards i'll get all the pros he needs, and decide. Again' iv'e attached a screenshot. The emoji meant to explain the user that this option is locked, would love to hear other suggestions :)

Comment: Attached a screenshot of the windows that pops after clicking the paid option

Comment: I would ask why do you need to provide the information in a second screen? If you present all the info at first: the user needs to do less clicks, you avoid the extra problem of making the user click to get that info.

Comment: basically because there are too much information, prices, pros etc, as you can see. As far as i can see, unfortunately, it's a needed click :/ where would you put all the info than?